# python class subclass or instances

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, subclass

Here is my first example of using python class and subclasses. A problem here is that attribute ParentUI is overrided.

```
class OptUI(object):
def __init__(self, ParentUI):
    self.ParentUI = ParentUI

class ListUI(object):
    def __init__(self, ParentUI):
        self.ParentUI = ParentUI

class Window(OptUI, ListUI):
    MainFrame = "MainFrame"
    TestFrame = "TestFrame"
    def __init__(self):
        OptUI.__init__(self, self.MainFrame)
        ListUI.__init__(self, self.TestFrame)
```

There is a solution if I use instances instead of inheritance in the Window class.

```
class Window(object):
    MainFrame = "MainFrame"
    TestFrame = "TestFrame"
    def __init__(self):
        self.OUI = OptUI(self.MainFrame)
        self.LUI = ListUI(self.TestFrame)
```

In the second case I have a quasi namespace for attribute ParentUI. So is this a good way in practice? Is this how it should be solved?

Comment: I think you should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to consider how your classes relate to each other, and then use that to determine how the code should be structured.

Inheriting implies an IS-A relationship between two classes. That is, instances of the derived class *are* instances of the base class. In your original code, the `Window` class is trying to inherit from both `OptUI` and `ListUI`, which might make sense if those two can overlap in a meaningful way and a `Window` object can *be* both at once. However, since the base classes both want to have a `ParentUI` variable with a different values, it may not make sense to be both of them at once (though it could also just be a design flaw of the `OptUI` or `ListUI` classes). You should come to your own conclusion about this, since I don't know what your classes actually mean.

On the other hand, including instances of the UI classes (known as "composition") doesn't make any statement about what interfaces the `Window` class should have. It suggest a HAS-A relationship, as each `Window` instance *has* an `OptUI` instance and a `ListUI` instance. If that makes more sense than an IS-A relationship, composition is definitely the way to go.

It might also make sense to do some of each. That is, inherit from one of the UI classes while containing an instance of the other. The `Window` instance might *be* an `OptUI` instance, while *having* a `ListUI` instance.